# Xamarin IOS hide bar back button

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, viewwillappear

I am trying to hide the back button from my navigationcontroller on a certain view(using storyboard)

I tried to hide the bar back button overriding the `ViewWillAppear`, but it does not seem to happen.

Here is the code:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
    this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton (true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

just change to :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton (true, false);
}
```

Comment: created a sample project here https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=756A9B00AE9A5E3B!18575&authkey=!APUMFzMbaV9Pw18&ithint=file%2c.zip

Comment: My fault, XCode did not register the header or .m file.. Works :) Thanks

Comment: @Blounty Shouldn't *both* versions work? I mean, what other `NavigationItem`can the controller have if not the one from the navigation controller? But that would probably by the item of the navigation controller if itself is embedded into another `
UINavigationController`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best answer which works well with xamarin forms too
Add this code in App delegate.This solved my problem too

UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment (new UIOffset (-100, -60), UIBarMetrics.Default);